# How do I save a plot created from hydroTSM::hydroplot?

Tags: r, hydrotsm

I have the plot generated by the following code:

```r
hydroTSM::hydroplot(as.zoo(series_xts[,i]),FUN=funcion,na.rm=TRUE,
    ptype="ts+boxplot+hist",pfreq=escalas,xlab='Tiempo',ylab=variable,
    var.unit=unidad,col=colores_pastel,main=names(series_xts[,i]))
```

How can I save it in my working directory as a png file?
I understand that it is of class `Histogram`

Answer (score 1):

You can open a png file and print the graph in it before closing it:

```
png(file = 'plotgraph.png', res = 300)

hydroTSM::hydroplot(as.zoo(series_xts[,i]),FUN=funcion,na.rm=TRUE,ptype="ts+boxplot+hist",pfreq=escalas,xlab='Tiempo',ylab=variable,var.unit=unidad,col=colores_pastel,main=names(series_xts[,i]))

dev.off()
```

this will save a file with 300 dpi called "plotgraph.png" in your working directory